# Add Contact Suffix to Quicksearch Results

Tags: quicksearch

How can we have the Contact's Suffix (Jr, et) show up in the dropdown results of the Quicksearch input? It's helpful for us as we have contacts with the same name but different suffixes.

Answer (score 2):

At Administer - Customize - Display Preferences, near the bottom there is "Individual Sort Name Format". If you change it to `{contact.last_name}{, contact.individual_suffix}{, }{contact.first_name}` then NEW and UPDATED contacts will start to appear in quicksearch as desired. The only thing is that existing contacts who haven't been re-saved will still appear the old way. If you only have a few then just go edit and re-save them.